# does any one know of a working way to trap 413 error page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

i have tried everything  ErorDocument and Redirect   everything via .htaccess  but it does nto respond.  404 does 500 does and all others do.. but not 413 .. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this helps

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2151527.php

http://forums.iis.net/p/1169257/1949057.aspx